# highlighting text in listview from linq query

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, linq

## Windows 10 Universal App

Hi,
i like highlight text in `ListView` from linq.
I´ve an `ListView`, `ListviewItemtemplate`, `DataTemplate`, `Textbox`.
The `Textbox` is binding.

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" Background="#FFCCD0D6" Margin="0,240,0,60" IsItemClickEnabled="True" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="1095" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Tapped="listView_Tapped" DoubleTapped="listView_DoubleTapped" SelectionChanged="listView_SelectionChanged">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Margin="4" Text="{Binding Vorname}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        <TextBlock Margin="4" Text="{Binding Nachname}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

I search with linq with text from a textbox.
This works fine. I get the items i searched. But know, how could i highlighted the searched text. I can´t find solution.

thanks for help

olli

Comment: Define *highlight* please. Change color, font, background, add animation, increase size or what?

Comment: I´d like to mark the text with yellow

Comment: Did you tried to google? [First result](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/409275/Highlight-Searched-Text-in-WPF-ListView).

Answer (score 2):

You wont get that easy, I had once that requirement from a client and I ended stripping TextBlock in five `<Run>` properties to cover all possible situation, the hard part was to process results and split strings accordingly:

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
    <Bold><Run Text="{Binding Text1}" /></Bold>
    <Run Text="{Binding Text2}" />
    <Bold><Run Text="{Binding Text3}" /></Bold>
    <Run Text="{Binding Text4}" />
    <Bold><Run Text="{Binding Text5}" /></Bold>
</TextBlock>
```

EDIT:
There is also a library that claim to do this task, I have never played with it but you can give it a try:
[HtmlTextBlock for WPF](https://htmltextblock.codeplex.com/)